# How to invoke "./configure; make; make install" on Android adb

Tags: android, production-environment

I have a program that I would like to install on an android phone (x86). The program can be installed on a Linux PC. The procedure of installing the program on the PC is:

```
$./configure
$make
$make install
```

Now I would like to do the above through android ADB so I can install it on the phone. What are the utilities needed? (I cannot find "make" in busybox http://www.busybox.net/live_bbox/live_bbox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Building your program directly on the phone probably isn't going to be practical. The number of dependencies that `make` will wind up invoking during the build process will be huge, and either not exist or not work well on the device itself.

It would be better to look at cross-compiling, where you use a different system to build a binary that is suitable for your device.

It wouldn't be possible to provide more specific info without more detail, but be warned: you're probably in for a big project.

Maybe start here? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2723240